# How do I create a File object in Java w/out using an absolute path name?

Tags: java, file-io, path

This is the path I'm using now:

```
C:\Users\Sabrina\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt
```

I tried just using the following:

```
C:\TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt
```

and

```
TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt
```

If I use either of those two Java will say "(The system cannot find the file specified)"...

`TriangleSumRecursion` is the java package that I'll turn in.

Comment: Relative paths depend on where you're running the program from. Run a jar file from the current directory and put the file in the same directory, or allow the filename to be passed in, or compile the file into the jar and use it as a resource, etc.

Comment: This is 2015; use java.nio.file.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the particular file into the project, and then try using `TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt`

You can import the file by right clicking on your project folder from your IDE, and then click on import. Follow the instructions and give the path of your file in it.

i hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use Slashes ('/'), not Backslashes ('\') in Javacode.
But besides of that, Java can handle absolute and relative paths.

> I tried just using the following: C:\TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt

This is not the right absolute path, if there is no folder 'TriangleSumRecursion' in C:\. Your working path example is the only right one.

> and TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt

Here you try this as a relative path. Java starts its search in the folder your file, running the code, is located. So this would work, if your java file was in 'C:\Users\Sabrina\Documents\NetBeansProjects'.
But since I think your file is in 'TriangleSumRecursion', the path you are looking for is simply 'lab4Data.txt'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following reading your file line by line, by first reading the file through a file reader, that is then fed to the buffered reader. Then you can create a string buffer, and as the program reads each line of the file it will append it to the string buffer. To check if it was successful just simply close the file reader and use the toString() method to display the contents of the file.

```
  `public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("lab4Data.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("File is:");
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

`C:\TriangleSumRecursion\lab4Data.txt` is an absolute path, so this will not identify your file which is not at this location.

You are more than probably in directory `C:\Users\Sabrina\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TriangleSumRecursion`, therefore a simple:

```
Paths.get("lab4Data.txt")
```

will give you a `Path` to your file (this is 2015; use java.nio.file and drop `File`).

But this is Windows and there are some strange things with Windows... Another way to access your file would be:

```
Paths.get("c:lab4data.txt")
```

Which is a path which has a root (`c:`) but which *is not* absolute (since such a path cannot be used to uniquely identify a resource on the `FileSystem`.

See the `Files` class on how to open, for instance, an `InputStream` or a `BufferedReader` from this file. And note that if the file does not exist the matching methods will throw a `NoSuchFileException`.

Last but not least, use a try-with-resources statement:

```
try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
) {
    // use the reader here
}
```